# Angular 2 login page that has different design from other pages

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-router

My main design is in app.component.html as normally. Other components use this one like master page. But how login page will have a different design. Normally it's a component like others and (must?) work in  in app.component.html.

I can't figure it out. Any advice?

Comment: I recommend dividing the application into smaller sub-apps based on layout for maintenance purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your AppComponent should look like this.

```
@Component({
    selector:'payroll-app',
    template:`<div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>`, //{{}} these four curly braces are called 'interpolation'
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [Utils,BonusService, ModelService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, DialogService]
})
```

And Login like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl:'./app/login/login.component.html',
    selector:'app-login',
    styleUrls:['./app/login/login.component.css'],
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Keep Default route like:

```
LoginRoutes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

When you your page will be loaded, router service will redirect you app by default to login page. This is how usual application works.

Comment: But you imagine AppComponent  has no html in it like a header or footer.

Comment: You could purely use AppComponent as the router outlet as shown above, then have two sub-components under it: the component that works as your master layout, and the login component, each with their own independent stylings.

Comment: if somebody need master layout then this AppComponent can have html tags. Hope it is understood

Answer (score 0):

You could use another angular application (login.component used in bootstrap) but you could also use a main component (e.g app.component) without a specific design. The main component without specific design then include a specific design depending on the page you want to display.